# Is it possible to have v.in.lidar without compiling GRASS?

Tags: grass-gis, installation, ubuntu, lidar, interoperability

I already have installed libLAS like this:

```
sudo apt-get install liblas-bin
```

And Ì have installed GRASS GIS 7 from the ubuntugis-unstable repository.

Is it possible v.in.lidar without compiling GRASS? I have tried to install it with:

```
g.extension extension=v.in.lidar
```

This gives the following error:

> URL 'http://svn.osgeo.org/grass/grass-addons/grass7/vector/v.in.lidar' doesn't exist
>   ERROR: GRASS Addons  not found

Is there any way to make this work? Or any other way to avoid to have to compile GRASS as a whole? I am not very familiar with the compilation process, and as [the guide](http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Compile_and_Install_Ubuntu) recommends, I am trying to keep things as simple as possible.

Comment: You may contact the maintainer to add liblas support in order to make r.in.lidar and v.in.lidar available, too.

Comment: How can i contact with him? Can i use the GRASS GIS wishlist or i should use other method?

Comment: The best will be to open a request at https://launchpad.net/~grass/+archive/ubuntu/grass-stable because then it reaches the Ubuntu-GIS maintainers.

Comment: I was unsure to which mail i should send the suggestion  (grass@lists.launchpad.net seemed to be for the internal use of the developers). Instead, i opened a ticket in the GRASS GIS tracker, asking for an enhancement: https://trac.osgeo.org/grass/ticket/2716#ticket

Comment: This suggestion is unlikely to happen, say, not quite realistic from a programmers' point of view. The solution is as simple as providing liblas in Ubuntu and compile GRASS GIS 7 with liblas support. Takes perhaps 20min to do that for the Ubuntu-GIS maintainer :-)

Comment: Sorry, i didn't understand , the idea is that the ubuntugis mantainers add a GRASS GIS package with liblas support, but i opened a pointless ticket in the GRASS mailing list instead... I have sent an email to the ubuntugis mailing list (ubuntu@lists.osgeo.org.) asking for the addition. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: What I meant to say: It would be ideal to get liblas into ubuntugis, then simply make them compile GRASS GIS with liblas support. Voilà...

Comment: They already applied the changes and everything seems to run. The conversation is here: http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/ubuntu/2015-August/thread.html

Comment: Great!! If all runs, please post it as full answer below to make this improvement obvious to all readers here. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the simplest answer is no.

The [GRASS LIDAR docs](http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/LIDAR) state:

> v.in.lidar - (GRASS 7 only; **GRASS must be compiled with libLAS support**).

Which the [GRASS 7.0 Ubuntu packages](https://launchpad.net/~grass/+archive/ubuntu/grass-stable) do not appear to have. From the latest [build log (amd64)](https://launchpadlibrarian.net/212160123/buildlog_ubuntu-vivid-amd64.grass7_7.0.1RC2-1~ubuntu15.04.1_BUILDING.txt.gz):

> GRASS is now configured for:  x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
>
> ...
>
> GDAL support:               yes
>     GEOS support:               yes
>     LAPACK support:             yes
>     Large File support (LFS):   yes
>     **libLAS support:             no**
>     MySQL support:              yes
>     NetCDF support:             yes
>     NLS support:                yes
>   ...

You will need to find an different package that does have that support built in, or build it yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your fast response! I was hoping there was any other method i didn't find. I suppose i will have to find a workaround to import the point clouds.

Comment: @opengisapprendice Have you seen [las2ogr](http://www.liblas.org/utilities/las2ogr.html)? If your GDAL installation is built with GRASS support (or with the plugin) you could use it to convert directly to a GRASS vector by the looks of it.

Comment: My initial idea was to use las2txt and import the archives with v.in.ascii, but i will try that too :)